# Passing lambdas directly to functions

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing an `Option` class which represents a value that may or may not exist. The `if_opt` function is intended to take an `Option` and a function which will be called on the value held in the `Option`, but only if the value exists.

```
template <class T>
class Option {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> m_value;
public:
    explicit operator bool()const noexcept
    {
        return (bool)m_value;
    }

    Option() = default;

    explicit Option(T value)
    {
        m_value =  std::make_shared<T>(value);
    }

    template <class U>
    friend void if_opt(Option<U>&, std::function<void(U&)>);
};

template <class T>
void if_opt(Option<T>& opt, std::function<void(T&)> f)
{
    if (opt) f(*opt.m_value);
};
```

I've noticed that this works if I use it like so:

```
Option<int> none;
Option<int> some(10);

function<void(int&)> f1 = [](int& none)
{
    cout << "This should never be reached" << endl;
};

function<void(int&)> f2 = [](int& some)
{
    cout << "The value of some is: " << some << endl;
};

if_opt(none, f1);

if_opt(some, f2);
```

But I'd like to be able to put the lambda expression directly in the call, but when I do:

```
if_opt(none, [](int&)
{
    cout << "This should never be reached" << endl;
});

if_opt(some, [](int& some)
{
    cout << "The value of some is: " << some << endl;
});
```

I get an error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'if_opt(Option<int>&, main()::<lambda(int&)>)'
```

I know that the type of a lambda expression is undefined in the standard, and that it merely has to be assignable to `std::function<R(T)>`, so this sort of makes sense, but is there a way that I can get the lambda argument to implicitly convert to a `std::function<void(T&)>` so that I can define the lambda in the call to `if_opt` the way I attempted?

Comment: `template <typename T, typename F> void if_opt(Option<T>& opt, F f) { ... }`

Comment: FWIW, there are implementations of `std::optional` that work with C++11. A `shared_ptr` for this is overkill, and so is `std::function` for `if_opt`, given that it's never stored.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik honestly that's all I wanted. I feel pretty dumb for not just doing that. I'd accept that as an answer.

Comment: @chris Thanks, I didn't know about `std::optional`

Comment: Are you aware that this is an invented wheel? `#include <optional>` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::function<Sig>` is a type erasure tool.  It erases (almost) everything about the value it stores excpet that it can be invoked with `Sig`.

Template argument deduction takes a passed in type and deduces what types should be used, then the template function is generated and (usually) called.

These are almost inverses of each other.  Doing deduction on a type erasure template is code smell, and almost always a bad idea.

So that is your fundamental design error.

---

There are a number of ways to fix your code.

First, `if_opt` shouldn't be a template.

```
friend void if_opt(Option<T>& opt, std::function<void(T&)> f){
  if (opt) f(*opt.m_value);
}
```

this creates what I call a Koenig friend.  You have to define the body inline.  Really, that `U` type is pointless, and can even lead to errors in some cases.

But the type erasure here is also pointless.  Fixing that returns the template, but now for a good reason.

```
template<class F>
friend void if_opt(Option<T>& opt, F&& f){
  if (opt) f(*opt.m_value);
}
```

this is a better design.

You can go and invest in SFINAE overload resolution code, but I wouldn't bother.

```
template<class F,
  std::conditional_t<true, bool,std::result_of_t<F&(T&)>> = true
>
friend void if_opt(Option<T>& opt, F&& f){
  if (opt) f(*opt.m_value);
}
```

the above is obscure and has minimal marginal advantages over the one above it.